# Need to run a processing demanding application on a .NET server.... any tips?

Tags: .net, web-services, client

I need to run an image processing application on a .NET server.
Do you have any tips what I should/can do?

I implemented the code in a webservice, but performance is very slow (at least 10x slower than when executed in a windows application).

Any help will be greatly appreciated.
thanks

Comment: A bit more information about the performance bottlenecks of your type of processing would be helpful.  Have you tried using a profiler (http://www.red-gate.com/products/ants_performance_profiler/index.htm, http://www.jetbrains.com/profiler/) to understand what's slow?

Comment: Avoid measuring the time needed to get the image across the wire.

Answer (score 0):

Your webservice should just create the queue within its request and return, it should process the images at that point.

I would run the same processing you have in your windows application in a windows service instead. Depending on the volumes and size of images you could restrict this to only processing a limited number of images processes at once or even just queue the processing to one image at a time.